# raid array not mounted

Tags: linux, raid

I have configured RAID array in my SUSE machine using `mdadm` command. The `/etc/mdadm.conf` is fine and `cat /proc/mdstat` shows up the array and it is also fine. However, if I run the `df -h` command, it is not showing the raid array.

Is there some step am missing?

Comment: not sure but is it possible that you forget to mount it?

Comment: Is there a filesystem on the array? You will need to do a `mkfs` before you use `df`.

Comment: Yeah, I believe there is a file system in it. Is there any other way to figure it out other than df to find if there is a file system in it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have LVM on top of your raid, you should just try to mount the array (assuming it is md0, but you can see the name from your `cat /proc/mdstat`)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/tmp
```

alternatively you can try:

```
sudo file -sL /dev/md0
```

to display the filesystem type of an unmounted device (assuming a filesystem was  of course created).

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly the same. It shows up in the df -h command. However, after editing the entry in /etc/fstab and rebooting all the entries are gone. I mean, the entire array is not present.

Comment: Did you check your /etc/mdadm.conf and /proc/mdstat?

Comment: Yeah, all the entries are gone. I don't have the entries inside those files.

Comment: So you probably did not have a ARRAY line in your mdadm.conf (mine is under /etc/mdadm/, are you look at the right file). Did you do `mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` ?

Comment: The thing was, I did not had any mdadm.conf file itself initially. I ran the command mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf and the file got created after the above command.

Comment: Like I indicated, the mdadm.conf on my server is in `/etc/mdadm/` not in `/etc`, but that is on Ubuntu (12.04). You probably just have to rerun the assemble command like you did before you ran the scan.

Comment: 'sudo -sL' ???  Command missing?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yup, I forgot the 'file' command, thanks